# How to change default image viewing app in Lotus Notes 8.5.1

Tags: windows, lotus-notes

I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5.1 and want to change the default application that opens image attachments (e.g., so images open in PhotoShop instead of Microsoft Viewer). Can anyone please advise how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be changed in Windows - and is as such not related to Lotus Notes.

Have a look at this Microsoft article on how to change the file type assocation:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859